# adding duplicate type of column to a datatable

Tags: asp.net

How can i add same fields for columns in a datatable. I wan to make a datatable which repeate column name of same type multiple times, but dot net dont allow me to add that, but i want to do that hw can i do that?

```
table.Columns.Add("S.NO", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("DC", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("DC", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("DC", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("ST", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("ST", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("AD", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("AD", typeof(string));
```

Comment: You **cannot** have two columns of the same name - period. If you have this case, you need to e.g. add a numerical postfix ("AD1", "AD2") or something - you **cannot** under any circumstances have two columns of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what relational database were created to avoid.  You should not repeat the same column in a table.  Instead, each instance of the column should become rows in a related table.

So a table like (SNo INTEGER, INFO STRING, ST STRING, ST STRING) would instead become two tables (SNo INTEGER, INFO STRING) and (SNo INTEGER, ST STRING).  The original "record" would become one record in the first table and two matching records (matching using the SNo value) in the second table.

Comment: But my requirement is something like that, i want to create a report of that kind which require me to duplicate the coulumn name....what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

You do it like this

```
   DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
                col.Caption = "Your Caption";
                col.ColumnName = "UniqueColumnName";
                col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                testDataTable.Columns.Add(col);
```

Just saying its bad practice is not helpful, we all know its bad practice, but for display purposes we sometimes need this ;)

Comment: I've been looking all over for a way to do this. It's bad practice depending on what you're doing. I'm showing exactly what is coming back from a query, which means there could be duplicate column names. Nothing wrong in displaying them that way in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, you can use binary null character:

```
string NullString= "\0";

table.Columns.Add("DC", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("DC" + NullString, typeof(string));
```